# Video file time length in minute while uploading to server in Spring or J2EE

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I want to save time length of the video files having several extension(mp4, wav, flv etc) in to database while uploading to server when submitting the page. But I did not find the how to get the length of the uploading video? I tried this code but it only works for audio files.

```
      File f = new File(fileName);
      Bitstream m_bitstream = new Bitstream(inputStream);
      Header m_header = m_bitstream.readFrame();
      int mediaLength = (int)f.length();
      int nTotalMS = 0;
      if (mediaLength != AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED) {
         nTotalMS = Math.round(m_header.total_ms(mediaLength));
      }
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please refere to this post for "wav" files

[How to learn .wav duration in Java media frame work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709508/how-to-learn-wav-duration-in-java-media-frame-work)

For mp3 files please refere to:

[How do I get a mp3 file's total time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046669/how-do-i-get-a-mp3-files-total-time-in-java)

For mp4 please refer to:

[Is there a Java API for mp4 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015393/how-to-handle-mp4-files-with-java)